# Hardware Throttling / Rate limit

Tags: algorithm, architecture, throttling, rate-limiting

My service uses 1*emphasized text* hardware resource per request. At any point of time, at-most X (lets say 100) number of such resources are available. What is the best technique I should use?

Point to note:

1. I have a distributed system.
2. I don't have to drop any request.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a semaphore. Or a queue of *hardware resource*. Without more information, it's impossible to say. You say, "I don't have to drop any request." Do you mean that you cannot drop requests?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a first-in-first-out queue per hardware resource. Every incoming request is assigned to the resource with the shortest queue.

If possible, you could also use a central queue and keep the reqests in this queue until a resource becomes available.

A mixed approach would be to partition the resources in groups and use one queue per group.